# Octave nan function with argument "single"

Tags: matlab, octave, nan

The code I'm reading has a line:

```
someData = nan(3, 4, 5, "single")
```

I can't find the documentation for the "nan" function, but this code appears to generate a 3x4x5 matrix of NaN. However, I don't know what "single" does. Replacing it with a random other string gets "error: NaN: invalid data type specified", and replacing it with "double" appears to give the same result. What is the function of the "single"?

Comment: The documentation on nan is found here http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html , and you can find information about data types here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type

Comment: What do you mean you can't find the documentation for the `nan` function? You just type `help nan` at the Octave promp. This is documented there: "The optional argument CLASS specifies the return type and may be either "double" or "single"".

Comment: Huh, why isn't it capitalization-sensitive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes the resulting matrix of `nan` a matrix that is of the [single-precision data type](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Single-Precision-Data-Types.html) which contains single-precision floating-point numbers. If you want single precision, you need to specify this explicitly, otherwise Octave and MATLAB will use double-precision by default.

You can check the class of the output using `class`.

```
class(nan(3, 4, 5, 'single'))
%  'single'

class(nan(3, 4, 5))
%  'double'
```

As far as looking the same, they *will* look the same until you start trying to store numbers that exceed the range of numbers that can be represented with single-precision floating point representation. This is because single precision numbers use half the amount of memory that double precision numbers do.

```
a = nan(1, 1, 'single');
a(1) = 1e-64
% 0

b = nan(1, 1);
b(1) = 1e-64
% 1.000e-64
```

Also if we inspect the variables with `whos` we can confirm the size difference.

```
a = nan(1,1,'single');
b = nan(1,1)
whos('a', 'b')

%    Variables in the current scope:
%   
%      Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
%      ==== ====        ====                     =====  =====
%           a           1x1                          4  single
%           b           1x1                          8  double
```

Comment: You should add that `whos` will show a different size of the matrix, since a single uses less memory than a double.